# How can an extern pointer to string literal declared in one C file be accessed in another C file?

Tags: c

I'm getting my sea legs with C, and I need a string literal which is discovered in a `main` function in one `.c` file to be accessible in an entirely different `.c` file.

What I've tried: I'm declaring a pointer to a string literal as `extern` in a header, defining it on one `.c` file, and trying to access the literal in a second `.c` file. Compilation is failing due to lack of definition in the second (accessing) file.

What I've got in a nutshell:

**file1.h** :

```c
extern char *global;
```

**file1.c** :

```c
#include "file1.h"

int main() {
     //some code
     extern char *global = some_struct->data;
     //more code
}
```

**file2.c** :

```c
#include "file1.h"

int do_stuff() {
     //some code
     some_function(global);
     //more code
}
```

I expected this to compile, since `global` is declared in `file1.h`, defined in `file1.c`, and its value accessed in `file2.c`. Compilation of `file2.c` fails, however, for undefined variable.

If relevant, the `main` function in `file1.c` is always the first function run in the program.

Comment: Did you try to put the definition on file scope instead of inside `main`?

Comment: I doubt that it is compilation of file2.c which fails. Instead linking of both files together should fail.

Comment: just assign _global_ in _main_ and add its definition in _file1.c_, see my answer

Comment: You do not understand my answer ? WHat is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

in *main*

> ```
>      extern char *global = some_struct->data;
> ```

is wrong, if you want to assign *global* do :

```
     global = some_struct->data;
```

and some where at global scope you need to define *global* :

```
char *global;
```

So for instance *main* become :

```
#include "file1.h"

char *global;

int main() {
     //some code
     global = some_struct->data;
     //more code
}
```

Comment: Thanks you (and also @ben-zotto) for taking the time to answer, but unfortunately when I define `global` outside of function scope in `file1.c`, on compilation, I still get an error for "undefined reference to `global`" in `file2.c`. One thing I forgot in my example is that `do_stuff` in `file2.c` is static, but I can't see how that would make any difference. Any idea where I still may be going wrong? Do I also need to make any change to `file2.c`?

Comment: @Jeff  it is **impossible** you have that error if you modified _file1.c_ as me (do not say me to make _global_ static for instance) and of course compiled it before to link with _file2.c_ (or at the same time doing `gcc *.c`). Check what you did

Comment: Got it. This is a huge application to which I'm just making a small modification, so I'll start looking through the Makefile to see if it's a compilation ordering thing. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but not quite there. The global variable must also be *defined* in the global scope, and you're running into the difference between *declaration* and *definition* (which are easy to get the wrong way round but the words don't matter as much as the idea). Normally, your statements that introduce a variable will both declare and define simultaneously, but not so with globals that are shared between modules like this:

In your `file1.h`, you are correctly *declaring* the `char*` variable in the global scope. Anyone who includes this file (e.g. `file2.c`) will "see" that the variable with that name should exist and all modules will compile cleanly, and the `extern` keyword makes explicit that you are only declaring this to exist, not creating storage for it yet. That is what you want, because you don't want to accidentally create multiple conflicting global variables with this name. When the compiled modules are eventually linked together, the linker will look for the actual memory storage space set aside for the global and connect all the references up correctly.

But in your case, that won't happen correctly, because although you have declared to the world that this global exists, you haven't yet actually created storage for the variable!

You still need to do this in the global scope (outside the functions) in `file1.h`:

```
char * global;
```

That creates the actual variable with the matching name to the extern declaration, and so the linker will be able to assemble your modules correctly.

So

```
#include "file1.h"

// Define global:
char * global;

int main() {
     // Assign a value to the global variable:
     global = some_struct->data;

     //more code
}
```

Note that you don't redeclare the extern or anything in this file, and you don't redefine the type of `global` inside `main`, because it already exists, and you can assign to it or look at its value. You also don't use the keyword `extern` here-- it is the "home" module for this variable.

Declaration and definition are generally just accomplished simultaneously, for example when you declare local variables within a function. Globals that are accessible from different modules rely on splitting the work into the two separate ideas so that both coworkers and the compiler and linker toolchain are not confused by your intentions.

Comment: @Jeff Saw your comments on the other answer. I concur that something else must be up in the build process. Note whether the error you're seeing is from the compiler when compiling file2.c, which seems unlikely since by itself file2.c should be internally consistent-- or whether it's from the linker when linking together all the modules. If the latter, then `global` perhaps somehow didn't end up in the global scope. If it's a big hairy project, maybe it accidentally ended up inside some large block of struct or function or something else?